# how to call child method in parent method?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Super struct{}

func (super *Super) name() string {
    return "Super"
}

func (super *Super) WhoAmI() {
    fmt.Printf("I'm %s.\n", super.name())
}

type Sub struct {
    Super
}

func (sub *Sub) name() string {
    return "Sub"
}

func main() {
    sub := &Sub{Super{}}
    sub.WhoAmI()
}
```

I want to get "I'm Sub", but I get "I'm Super" instead.

I already know sub.WhoAmI will call sub.Super.WhoAmI, but I still want to know if there is a way to get "I'm Sub". In Python when I write following code:

```
class Super(object):

    def name(self):
        return "Super"

    def WhoAmI(self):
        print("I'm {name}".format(name=self.name()))

class Sub(Super):

    def name(self):
        return "Sub"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sub  = Sub()
    sub.WhoAmI()
```

I can get "I'm Sub".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Embedding is not subclassing. There are no superclasses or subclasses in Go. `Sub` here is not a "child" of `Super`. It contains a `Super`. You can't do you're trying to do. You need to organize your code in a different way so that it's not needed.

For example, here ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/0_qZQ-V7EO)) is a more natural way to do this in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Namer interface {
    Name() string
}

type Super struct{}

func (sub *Super) Name() string {
    return "Super"
}

type Sub struct{}

func (sub *Sub) Name() string {
    return "Sub"
}

func WhoAmI(namer Namer) {
    fmt.Printf("I'm %s.\n", namer.Name())
}

func main() {
    sub := &Sub{}
    WhoAmI(sub)
}
```

Rather than focus on classes (which Go doesn't have), this focuses on interfaces. It's not a question of what things *are*, it's a question of what they can *do*. This is a very powerful approach to programming, and in practice is often much more flexible and less error-prone than inheritance abstractions.

Comment: Using interface it means you have to multiple the code, like `WhoAmI` method, it repeatedly shows in both `Sub` and `Parent` struct. I think passing object and use `reflect.ValueOf(&Sub{}).MethodByName("WhoAmI").Call(nil)` is a better option

Answer (score 2):

Think of functions in Go as if they all belong to a single namespace. Go really doesn’t have classes, methods, or inheritance, so what you’re attempting will never work the way you intend.

To put it another way, when you define a function like this:

```
func (f *Foo) DoStuff()
```

You can imagine it *really* being defined as:

```
func DoStuff(f *Foo)
```

So you might notice why Go chose to call the `name` function on your `Super` struct—it was the only function signature that matched. (Note that in your `WhoAmI` function `super` is defined as `super *Super` so Go matches it up with the corresponding function of the same type.)

As for how you might do this the Go way, try using interfaces:

**http://play.golang.org/p/8ELw-9e7Re**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Indentifier interface {
    WhoAmI() string
}

type A struct{}

func (a *A) WhoAmI() string {
    return "A"
}

type B struct{}

func (b *B) WhoAmI() string {
    return "B"
}

func doSomething(x Indentifier) {
    fmt.Println("x is a", x.WhoAmI())
}

func main() {
    doSomething(&A{})
    doSomething(&B{})
}
```